# Android Management API - Setting issue

Tags: android, kiosk, android-management-api

I am working on Android Managament API by Google. I need to disable all possibile access to menu settings except to "Wifi Menu". I am using a Kiosk App.

Now, I disabled the access from the policy but I still am to able to access and navigate in menu system with a simple click on the back arrow button in the left top corner from opening the wifi menu.

[image url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKiAw.png)

is It a google bugs?

My policy is:

```
"kioskCustomization": {
    "statusBar": "NOTIFICATIONS_AND_SYSTEM_INFO_ENABLED",
    "deviceSettings": "SETTINGS_ACCESS_BLOCKED",
    "systemNavigation": "HOME_BUTTON_ONLY",
    "powerButtonActions": "POWER_BUTTON_BLOCKED"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there is a feature in AMAPI where you can only access the WIFI menu. About the `deviceSettings:”SETTINGS_ACCESS_BLOCKED”`, it will block all the settings menu and you should not be able to navigate in the menu system. I tried using this on public apps like Instagram, Youtube and a private app but I wasn’t able to access the Menu Settings using the back arrow button.

In the other scenario I made, I created a private app to access WIFI Menu using a settings intent like `WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK` and  I was able to access the Menu System.

We have identified a bug that is currently being investigated by our Engineering team and for which a fix is about to be released.

I suggest joining the Android Management API mailing list to keep you posted on the latest updates.